# Android studio, File.properties deleted after reopening the app

Tags: java, android, file

I saved a File.properties in  `this.getFilesDir() + "Data.propertie"`.
In the app, I save the data that the user wrote, but when i open the app, all the data (or the file) that I saves from the previous time has been deleted.

Example:

```
        // Store
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : MainActivity.Notes.entrySet()) { // Put all data from Notes in properties to store later
            properties.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        try { properties.store(new FileOutputStream(this.getFilesDir() + "data.properties"), null); } // Store the data
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } // Error exception

        // Load the map
        Properties properties = new Properties(); // Crate properties object to store the data


        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(this.getFilesDir() + "data.proprties")); } // Try to load the map from the file
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } // Error exception

        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            Notes.put(key, properties.get(key).toString()); // Put all data from properties in the Notes map
        }

// Can load the data
```

You can see that i saved the data in the file, and I can load it, but when I open the app, the data has been deleted

**There is a way to write in the file and save the data that i write to the next time I open the app?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off [`Context.getFilesDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getFilesDir()) returns a `File` object. This `File` represents the private data directory of your app.

Then you do `getFilesDir() + "foo"` which will implicitly call `toString()` on the `File` instance. [`File.toString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File#toString()) is equivalent to `File.getPath` which does not necessarily return a trailing slash.

This means, if `getFilesDir()` returns a `File` at `/data/app`, your properties file will become `/data/appdata.properties` which is not in your data Folder and cannot be written to.

Instead, to get a `File` within a directory you can create a new `File` instance with that directory. e.g:

```java
File propertiesFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "data.properties");
// use propertiesFile for FileOutputStream/FileInputStream etc.
```

This ensures that your properties file is within that directory and prevents any issues from file separators

Comment: Thank's! I've been working on it for two days now, I was about to give up

Comment: @ZivSion Glad to help! As a recommendation, always try to work with `File` objects instead of constructing paths through strings. Most classes/libraries use `File` anyways instead of passing paths (FileInputStream have constructors which accept both).

Comment: Also, from your code, you should have seen an error/exception in the logcat. Always helps to look at that and if you need further help on stackoverflow, the logcat is usually very useful to provide as information :)